# when saving the values of an array in CoreData, only one value is saved

Tags: core-data, foreach, swiftui, save

I have an array which I want to add to a CoreData database, I have made a forEach to go through the array and then save the data in CoreData, the problem that only saves a value, below I write the code, There is a problem in the code?

```
class AquarisB: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    
    @NSManaged public var nombre : String

}



struct Inici: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        
        var data : Array = [nombre: test1, nombre: test2]
        var nuevoAcuari = Aquaris(context: self.contexto)
        
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var contexto
        
        
        data.forEach { (temp) in
            nuevoAcuari.nombre = temp.nombre
        }
        
        do {
            try self.contexto.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error al guardar", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not saving the array, your iterating over it, and updating the value of the `nombre` on your `nuevoAcuari`. Probably your entry in core data will be the last entry in the array.  You will need to create a new `Aquaris` for each entry in the array rather than try to repurpose the same one multiple times.

Comment: @andrew Could you say how should I implement the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you need to create a new entity for each item in your data array. Something like this should be enough.

```
for nombre in data {
    var nuevoAcuari = Aquaris(context: contexto)
    nuevoAcuari.nombre = nombre
}

do {
    try self.contexto.save()
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("error al guardar", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

The managed object context acts as a scratch pad, each time you create an object on it, it is not saved until you call save on it explicitly. If you want to add multiple items then you need to create them and then call save.

In your code all you are doing is updating the object that you have created and then calling save on it. You need to create an object for each item that that you wish to save.